# scanning from feeder, only the first page is scanned

Tags: kde, scanner, canon, xsane, simplescan

I have Canon MF237 printer/scanner. My OS is ubuntu kde.

When I try to scan with simple-scan/xsane/gscan2pdf with the feeder, the feeder goes through all the pages and loops through all of them but the scanning app shows only the first page.

This also happened on my previous samsung printer.

Is this a known problem for multi-page feeder scanning in current software/drivers? Has anybody encountered this problem and was able to fix it?

**update 1**

I have tried using cli scanimage. This happens also there but with slight more insight. There is seems to be some cancelation on the second page scanning?

```
scanimage --source "Automatic Document Feeder" --format tiff
--batch=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_p%04d.tiff  --resolution 150

Scanning infinity pages, incrementing by 1, numbering from 1 
Scanning page 1 
Scanned page 1. (scanner status = 5) 
Scanning page 2 
scanimage: sane_read: Operation was cancelled 
Scanned page 2. (scanner status = 2) 
Batch terminated, 2 pages scanned
```

Comment: I solved all my scanning problems with VueScan, I suggest you try it https://www.hamrick.com/

Answer (score 4):

If you are using XSane, in the main control window set the number of pages to scan (top LH corner) to greater than or equal to the number of pages in your stack, then set the transport mode to ADF (not Flatbed). Set operation type to Multipage or Save (make sure you have a trailing page number in the file name). Check the area to scan in the preview window. Load up the stack and press "Scan".

I found the answer here:
https://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16559/~/only-the-first-page-is-being-scanned-when-scanning-multi-page-document

Good luck
jg

Answer (score 0):

XSane's dialog has a "page amount" field on top-left - see image below. It's strange and unexpected that you'd need to specify page amount when using a feeder. Furthermore, I found it tried to generate a new file for each page, leading to an "Overwrite file" dialog. Overall not practical.

[image: XSane dialog section]

I would therefore suggest using XSane only to set up a scanner. After that, use [another app](https://opensource.com/life/14/8/3-tools-scanners-linux-desktop) like Simple Scan.

Answer (score 0):

SEE ALSO
[Multiple page scan using scanimage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383568/multiple-page-scan-using-scanimage)

" --batch-count count specifies the number of pages to attempt to scan. If not given, scanimage will continue scanning until the scanner returns a state other than OK. Not all scanners with document feeders signal when the ADF is empty, use this command to work around them".